# Problem with arg in NODE.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im have problem with node.js, i trying to get arg users, but its empty. Can someone help me? 
Проблем с нодой. Пытаюсь вывести переменную users за пределы цикла, но передается только [].

```
var users = [];      
var sql = 'SELECT * FROM ladder_lobbies_games LEFT JOIN ladder_lobbies ON ladder_lobbies_games.lobby_g_lobby=ladder_lobbies.lobby_id LEFT JOIN ladder_teams ON ladder_lobbies.lobby_team1=ladder_teams.id WHERE lobby_g_id = '+ lobbygame + ' LIMIT 1';
    connection.query(sql, function(err, rows, results) {

            var players = rows[0].players.split(',');
            players.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {
                    var sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = '+ item;
                    connection.query(sql, function(err, rows, results) {
                            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                                    users[i] = rows[i].user_steamid;
                            }
                    });                            
            });

    });
    logger.debug(users);
```

Comment: переведите, пожалуйста, на русский язык. внести изменения можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: Перевел на русский

Comment: все потому, что _connection.query_ это асинхронная операция, и когда вы вызываете _logger.debug(users);_ она может быть еще не закончена, следовательно и массив _user_ может быть не за полнен

Comment: Извини за тупость, но каким образом мне заставить ее выполнятся в первую очередь?

Comment: никаким, можно только использовать _Promise_, `connection.query` наверняка его возвращает, и добавлять лог когда запрос уже выполнен

Comment: А что если я буду получать информацию при помощи отдельного js скрипта и просто передавать его в мой?

Comment: никакой разницы если в нем все равно будет использован этот connection.query

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что из-за своей асинхронности JS не ждет окончания функции `connection.query` и сразу переходит к части `logger.debug(users);`
Можно решить проблему через использование промисов или решить в лоб, изменив код на такой:

```
var users = [];      
var sql = 'SELECT * FROM ladder_lobbies_games LEFT JOIN ladder_lobbies ON ladder_lobbies_games.lobby_g_lobby=ladder_lobbies.lobby_id LEFT JOIN ladder_teams ON ladder_lobbies.lobby_team1=ladder_teams.id WHERE lobby_g_id = '+ lobbygame + ' LIMIT 1';
connection.query(sql, function(err, rows, results) {

        var players = rows[0].players.split(',');
        players.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {
                var sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = '+ item;
                connection.query(sql, function(err, rows, results) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                                users[i] = rows[i].user_steamid;
                        }
                        logger.debug(users);
                });                            
        });

});
```